# Formatting expanded JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON Object something like this. While used with `JSON.stringify(Object)` it looks something like this.

```
 "[
    ["Individual Id","Individual Last Name","Individual First Name","Individual Middle Name"],
    ["1268933","mrs","jeanine","marie"]
    ["1268934","mr","jasmine","curry"]
 ]"
```

What is the fastest way to reformat the data as the below format.

```
[
{
    "Individual Id": "1268933",
    "Individual Last Name": "mrs",
    "Individual First Name": "jeanine",
    "Individual Middle Name": "marie"
},
{
    "Individual Id": "1268934",
    "Individual Last Name": "miss",
    "Individual First Name": "jasmine",
    "Individual Middle Name": "curry"
}
]
```

Comment: Dump it in a validator like [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com).

Comment: I want to do it in Code. So that i can post to my API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `array#shift` the first array and then using `array#map` and `array#reduce` generate the array.

```js
var arr = [["Individual Id","Individual Last Name","Individual First Name","Individual Middle Name"],["1268933","mrs","jeanine","marie"],["1268934","mr","jasmine","curry"]],
  headers = arr.shift(),
  result = arr.map(a => a.reduce((r,v,i) => (r[headers[i]] = v, r), {}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate twice. Once on the arrays containing values(data) and inside that iterate over keys in the first array.

```js
var arr = [
    ["Individual Id","Individual Last Name","Individual First Name","Individual Middle Name"],
    ["1268933","mrs","jeanine","marie"],
    ["1268934","mr","jasmine","curry"]
 ];
 var newArr = [];
 for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
  var obj = {};
  for(var j=0; j < arr[0].length; j++){
    obj[arr[0][j]] = arr[i][j];
  }
  newArr.push(obj);
 }
 console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: I believe other solutions that implement map and reduce will be faster for large objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and create your objects as needed:

```js
const arr = [
  ["Individual Id","Individual Last Name","Individual First Name","Individual Middle Name"],
  ["1268933","mrs","jeanine","marie"],
  ["1268934","mr","jasmine","curry"]
]

const result = arr.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    return prev
  }

  return [
    ...prev,
    {
      [arr[0][0]]: curr[0],
      [arr[0][1]]: curr[1],
      [arr[0][2]]: curr[2],
      [arr[0][3]]: curr[3],
    }
  ]
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ES6 features (*destructuring and rest operator*):

```js
var datas = [["Individual Id","Individual Last Name","Individual First Name","Individual Middle Name"], ["1268933","mrs","jeanine","marie"],["1268934","mr","jasmine","curry"]];

var [ fields, ...rows] = datas;
var result = rows.map(values => values.reduce((item, value, index) => (item[fields[index]] = value, item), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [
    ["Individual Id","Individual Last Name","Individual First Name","Individual Middle Name"],
    ["1268933","mrs","jeanine","marie"],
    ["1268934","mr","jasmine","curry"]
 ];

var values = a.splice(1,a.length-1);
var keys = a[0];
var result = [];
for(var i = 0,m=values.length;i<m;i++)
{
    var obj = {};
    for(var j=0,n=keys.length;j<n;j++)
    {
        obj[keys[j]] = values[i][j];
    }
    result.push(obj);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I believe other solutions that implement map and reduce will be faster for large objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `reduce`

```
var keys = inputArr[ 0 ];
var output = inputArr.slice(1).map( function( item ){
   return Object.keys( keys ).reduce( ( a, c ) => ( a[ keys[ c ] ] = item[c], a ), {});   
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var inputArr = [
    ["Individual Id","Individual Last Name","Individual First Name","Individual Middle Name"],
    ["1268933","mrs","jeanine","marie"],
    ["1268934","mr","jasmine","curry"]
];
var keys = inputArr[ 0 ];
var output = inputArr.slice(1).map( function( item ){
   return Object.keys( keys ).reduce( ( a, c ) => ( a[ keys[ c ] ] = item[c], a ), {});   
});
console.log( output );
```